# Ansible Playbook that runs 2nd play as different user

Tags: server, ansible, provisioning

The goal is to have only 1 playbook, that can be executed with the initial password setup when the os is built.
This playbook will add a service account, and then execute the remaining plays as that service account.
The issue im having is that the subsequent plays are not using the service account correctly.
Does anyone have any advice on how to get his method to work?
I can see that its using the new account, but its not passing the password for that new account.

my playbook is below

```
---
    #name: Playbook to run through roles to provision new server
  - hosts: all
    gather_facts: false
    become: true
    #become_user: '{{ root_user }}' #this is commented out to show what acct is being used    
    tasks: 
      #User root account to add new service account, so root account can also be managed.
      - name: Add Service Accounts
        include_tasks: ../steps/ServiceAccount_add.yml 

      - name: Pause for 30 seconds
        ansible.builtin.pause:
          seconds: 30

#2nd play to be ran as service account so root is not used.
  - hosts: all
    gather_facts: false
    become: true
    remote_user: '{{ Service_Account }}'
    become_user: '{{ Service_Account }}'
    vars:
      ansible_become_password: '{{ Service_AccountPW }}'
      remote_user_password: '{{ Service_AccountPW }}'
    tasks: 
      - name: Run Baseline
        include_tasks: ../steps/Yum_baseline.yml

      - name: Run Update
        include_tasks: ../steps/Yum_Update.yml
```

Everything executes up to this part:

```
<IPADDRESS> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d8 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'User="service_account"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/tmp/bwrap_656_m3k5zy9e/awx_656_4iz9_26u/cp/a07c97f8e1 IPADDRESS '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'"'"''
<IPADDRESS> (5, '', 'Permission denied, please try again.\r\nPermission denied, please try again.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n')
fatal: [IPADDRESS]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Invalid/incorrect password: Permission denied, please try again.\r\nPermission denied, please try again.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Comment: <unrelated> Why become the same user as the one your are connecting as? You can drop `become`, `become_user` and `ansible_become_password` in your second play </unrelated> The variable to set the connection password is `ansible_password` (with aliases `ansible_ssh_pass` and `ansible_ssh_password`) and **not** `remote_user_password`. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#parameter-password

Comment: Thank you, attempting these changes now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! @Zeitounator for his comment!

Here is the final code that works

```
---
    #name: Playbook to run through roles to provision new server
  - hosts: all
    gather_facts: false
    become: true
    #become_user: '{{ root_user }}'    
    tasks: 
      #User root account to add new service account, so root account can also be managed.
      - name: Add Service Accounts
        include_tasks: ../steps/Ansible_accountadd.yml 

      #Jeff Geerling suggested looking into this
      - name: Reset ssh connection to allow user changes to affect 'current login user'
        ansible.builtin.meta: reset_connection

#2nd play to be ran as service account so root is not used.
  - hosts: all
    gather_facts: false
    remote_user: '{{ Service_Account }}' # this is used to change the ssh user
    vars:
      ansible_ssh_pass: '{{ Service_AccountPW }}' #set the ssh user pw
    tasks: 
      - name: Run Baseline
        include_tasks: ../steps/Yum_baseline.yml

      - name: Run Update
        include_tasks: ../steps/Yum_Update.yml
```